# How to write path to location in XML/WSDL doc in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xsd, wsdl, savon

I have a WSDL doc with XSD import.

```
 <xsd:import namespace="http://site.com" schemaLocation="schema.xsd"/>
```

WSDL tool assumes that schema is in the same directory, but load fails in rails with error

```
 <RuntimeError: Unable to find schema for "http://site.com">
```

I've tried write path from rails root and from system root, but with no success.

I use Savon 3 to deal with WSDL in rails. SoapUI works with this schemas normally.

So, what is the right way to write this path?

Comment: Kirill, which version of savon? It behaves really really different from version to version

Comment: I am not so familiar with the toolset you've described, but did hear a lot of limitations in connection with stacks such as yours. If your referenced XSDs DO NOT USE xsd:include, then, if it's not that much to do, try to inline all the XSDs (i.e. copy their content) inside the WSDL file, then make sure you remove all the schemaLocation attributes of all the schema imports and run again. Many tools in my past experience failed miserably when XSDs are all over the place, but worked when all content is embedded in one WSDL file.

Comment: It appears that inlining doesn't help so much in this case, as xsd:import suggests namespace usage and you can have only single namespace in single xsd file. I've solved my problem by placing files online and make absolute url path. It's rather poor decision, but it works. (This comment is mostly for future reference)