# WSDL import not working with savon 2.3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, wsdl, ruby-1.9.3, savon

I am using `Savon 2.3` to call a web service with a wsdl file, but my wsdl file is divided into three files binding, operations and definition where the three reference each other like this `binding -> operations -> definition`.

In *binding.wsdl* I have following line which imports *operations.wsdl*:

`<wsdl:import location="operations.wsdl" namespace="http://site.com"/>`

and in my *operations.wsdl* I have the following which imports *definition.wsdl* :

`<wsdl:import location="definition.wsdl" namespace="http://site.com/">`

but when I call `operations` with `Savon.client` object, the operation defined in wsdl file is not returned with `client.operations` but when I am combine the three files `:authenticate_user`, which is defined in the wsdl file, is returned in the array like this:

```
1.9.3p448 :014 > client = Savon.client(wsdl: "binding.wsdl", wsse_auth: ["Username","Password"])
1.9.3p448 :014 > client_combined = Savon.client(wsdl: "combined.wsdl", wsse_auth: ["Username","Password"])

1.9.3p448 :016 > client.operations
 => [] 
1.9.3p448 :017 > client_combined.operations
 => [:authenticate_user]
```

My questions is why is `Savon` not importing the corresponding wsdl files into one and then using it or am I missing something.

This question is pretty similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518266/how-to-write-path-to-location-in-xml-wsdl-doc-in-rails), but as I read Ivan's comment that it behaves differently from version to version and I am using `Savon 2.3.0.`, I thought it would be better to ask this separately.

Comment: Looks like only version 3 can handle imports:  https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Vimsha's comment `Savon 2.3.0` does not support `xsd/wsdl: import`, this is because the parser used by `Savon` is very basic and lacks the feature to resolve imports. `Savon` uses [wasabi](https://github.com/rubiii/wasabi) for parsing.

This has been resolved in `Savon 3`, please see this [thread](https://github.com/savonrb/wasabi/issues/27).

If you still have problem with imports in `Savon 3` you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518266/how-to-write-path-to-location-in-xml-wsdl-doc-in-rails).